# Unable to download file with content type text/html

Tags: java, pdf, url, content-type, fileinputstream

I have one URL which will download the pdf file when I try it on the browser directly. But when I use the same URL to download the file using FileInputStream in Java code, I'm getting an issue like a content type of URL is text/html, instead of application/pdf because of which we are unable to open the file as the content type inside the URL is not pdf.

Here the confusion comes, how come I'm able to download the file from the browser when the content-type is not application/pdf?

Anything wrong with the code?

```java
String pdfUrl = service.getPdfUrl(bpaRequest);
URL url1 = new URL(pdfUrl);
FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
System.out.print("Connecting to " + url1.toString() + " ... ");
URLConnection urlConn = url1.openConnection();

// Checking whether the URL contains a PDF
if (!urlConn.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("application/pdf")) {
    throw new CustomException("INVALID_CONTENT", "contentType is not pdf");
} else {
    InputStream is1 = url1.openStream();
    while ((baLength = is1.read(ba1)) != -1) {
        fos1.write(ba1, 0, baLength);
    }
    fos1.flush();
    fos1.close();
    is1.close();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use application/octet-stream for file downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it looks like url is redirected into another URL from which real content is downloaded.

You need to get check the `Location` header and if its non null then get value from header close connection and open new one on that link.

Then when you invoke method getContentType() it will be application/pdf

Comment: But Im getting content type for URL is text/html, can I set the content type explicitely?

Comment: Content type can be any like text/html etc. Updated answer

Comment: You want me to set the Content-Disposition for URL?

Comment: Show please full sample

Comment: Please share url from which you are downloading , I have tried https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/pdf/spring-boot-reference.pdf
Works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212335/discussion-between-mykhailo-moskura-and-veswanth).